# how to count value in object javascript

Tags: javascript

hay , i have JSON format like this from looping

```
let data = {
        status: "0"
        description: "item 1"
}

{
        status: "1"
        description: "item 1"

}
```

i want to get value **status** and count how many **status** with value **0**

expected output like this :

```
let gg = "status 0 as much 1"
```

how to do this in javascript ? thanks

Comment: That isn't JSON. JSON is a *textual notation* for data exchange. [(More here.)](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2904181/157247) If you're dealing with JavaScript source code, and not dealing with a *string*, you're not dealing with JSON. If it **were** meant to be JSON, it wouldn't be correct, because the keys aren't in double quotes and there are no commas between the properties. Also, what you've shown doesn't make much sense, you have an object followed by what's prob meant to be another object but with no structure around them (like an array). What's your **actual** data you're working with?

Comment: It's also invalid as a JS object. There are commas missing.

Answer (score 1):

First your JSON is invalid. Possibly what you want is an array that contains objects that you can iterate over. You need to quote your data properly, and include commas where they're required.

```
'[{ "status": "0", "description": "item 1" }, { "status": "1", "description": "item 1" } ]'
```

Once you have valid JSON and you've [parsed it](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse) you can iterate over the objects.

Here's a function that passes in the parsed data, and the desired property and value as arguments. It [`filters`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) out the objects that match the condition, and [returns a string](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals) with the details.

```js
const data = [{ status: '0', description: 'item 1' }, { status: '1', description: 'item 1' }, { status: '0', description: 'item 1' } ];

function getStatus(data, type, value) {

  // `filter` out the objects where the property key matches the value
  const out = data.filter(obj => obj[type] === value);

  // Return a template string with the details
  return `status ${value} as much ${out.length}`;
}

console.log(getStatus(data, 'status', '0'));
```

Answer (score -1):

You missed some commas but I think you want something like

Edited
If you are trying to extract this from an object with property keys you should use..

```
Object.values(obj).reduce((acc, cur) => !cur.status ? acc + 1 : acc, 0)
```

If it's an array
arr.reduce((acc, cur) => !cur.status ? acc + 1 : acc, 0)

Like others have said the object in the question is not valid

Comment: Where do you think the "missing commas" go to make that a valid object in the question?

Comment: well, do you think that's valid?

Comment: Youre right there's a lot more than commas missing from it..